# PS4 digital games on external hdd

Tags: ps4, psn, digital-distribution

I just bought a new PS4 and I was asking myself: is it possible to download games on an external hdd using a PC?! 
For example: I'm using my PS4 on the WLAN1 at home but I want to download PS4's game on an external hdd using a PC on the WLAN2 at work. 
I know it may sound like I'm asking how to download illegal copies of the game but the real reason is very simple: my apartment is not reached by any kind of dsl so I have to use WiMax (and downloading something with a WiMax connection can take from 4 to 6 days). At work instead I have a 100mbit connection.
So, basically, my question is this: is it possible to download games (***VIA PSN***) using a PC on an external hdd?!

Comment: There's the possibility to download content from the PlaystationStore from a remote location to your PS4. http://faq.en.playstation.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/9487/~/how-to-download-purchases-to-your-ps4™

Comment: @vkvau, that's a possibility to **start** download remotely, actual downloading is still done by PS4.

Comment: @icebat I am aware of that but failed to point that out. Thanks for your remark. Since it's not answering OP's question, I thought he might find my method useful. I usually access the Store using my phone or computer and order my Playstation to download games.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not, the only way to download digital games from PSN currently is via a console.

You *could* take your PS4 + external drive to work and do it that way, but I don't think this is what you're looking to do (And that way you could just take the PS4 itself).

Comment: I'm just looking for a way to download digital contents with another connection WITHOUT bringing with me the console... :(

Comment: Yeah, it is strange to me they still don't provide this as standard :/